# OpenLDAP Child or Relay server configuration assistance

Tags: ldap, openldap, ldapsearch

I am a really lost here and would appreciate some help.

My organization already maintains an OpenLDAP server which allows read-only access

Running this gives me an entire dump of all the users and groups and OUs in my organization.

```
ldapsearch -x -b dc=corp,dc=ORG,dc=com -H ldap://xx.eng.yy.ORG.com
```

This is good, now I have the organization hierarchy in my hand.

---

Next, I want to create an OpenLDAP server and have this server "override" groups that are not present in the parent OpenLDAP server, so for example in the Parent/Main LDAP server:

There is an `OU=support` in which there's 100s of users. I want to add more granularity to these users.

What I would like to do on my CHILD LDAP server is:

- Create a new group named `Support-NewHires`
- Add a small number of users from `OU=support` in this new group.

So when I use CHILD ldap server anywhere and login as one of the users in `Support-NewHires`, the LDAP query will be forwarded to the PARENT LDAP server (for passwords) but the permissions would be set according to where I configured `Support-NewHires` to access.

Lets say John is a new hire in `OU=Support` and Jane is a veteran in `OU=Support`.
So, I add John to `OU=Support-NewHires`

Now I have an application with LDAP integration (VMware vCenter), I would integrate with CHILD LDAP server.
I will set restricted Access Controls for `OU=Support-NewHires` group and Full Control access to `OU=Support` group

Now when John logs in, he will see the restricted view, but if Jane logs in she will get the unrestricted view.
I wont have to deal with storing any of their passwords or other details, just their `UID=`

Note that I *do not* have write permissions to access PARENT LDAP server.